# jquery ajax not returning data on android

Tags: jquery, android, ajax, json

I have a jQuery Ajax function that creates multiple lists of links from json data. It works on all web browsers IE, FF, Safari, Chrome, Opera, and it works on iPhone, iTouch, and iPad. For some reason it does not work on Android:

```
function FetchListsMobTest(thislist) {
    var thislist;
    if (thislist == "comp") {
        $('<div id="wrapper"></div>').html('<div id="comp1"><div id="companies"></div></div>').appendTo("#firstlist");
    } if (thislist == "prod") {
        $('<div id="wrapper"></div>').html('<div id="prod1"><div id="products"></div></div>').appendTo("#secondlist");
    } if (thislist == "stan") {
        $('<div id="wrapper"></div>').html('<div id="stan1"><div id="standards"></div></div>').appendTo("#thirdlist");
    } if (thislist == "cert") {
        $('<div id="wrapper"></div>').html('<div id="cert1"><div id="certified"></div></div>').appendTo("#fourthlist");
    }
    var Params = {};
    Params.type = "get",
    Params.url = "javascript/directories.js",
    Params.data = "data",
    Params.dataType = "json",
    Params.cache = false,
    Params.contentType = "application/json",
    Params.processData = true,
    Params.callbackParameter = "callback",
    Params.error = function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(xhr.errorThrown); },
    Params.success = function (data) {
        $.each(data.directory, function (i, data) {
            var Company2 = '' + data.Company + '';
            var Product2 = '' + data.Product + '';
            var Standard2 = '' + data.Standard + '';
            var Certify2 = '' + data.Certified + '';
            if (thislist == "comp") {
                $('<div class="company" style="text-align:left;border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;margin: 0px;padding-top: 0.5em;padding-left: 0.4em;padding-right: 0px;padding-bottom: 0.5em;font-size: 0.9em;line-height: 100%;"></div>').html('<a href="listingsMob.html?Company=' + Company2 + '" target="_top" style="text-decoration: none;padding-left: 10px;background-image: url(images/open_arrow.gif);background-position: bottom left;background-repeat: no-repeat;">' + Company2 + '</a>').appendTo("#companies");
            } if (thislist == "prod") {
                $('<div class="product" style="text-align:left;border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;margin: 0px;padding-top: 0.5em;padding-left: 0.4em;padding-right: 0px;padding-bottom: 0.5em;font-size: 0.9em;line-height: 90%;"></div>').html('<a href="listingsMob.html?Product=' + Product2 + '" target="_top" style="text-decoration: none;padding-left: 10px;background-image: url(images/open_arrow.gif);background-position: bottom left;background-repeat: no-repeat;">' + Product2 + '</a>').appendTo("#products");
            } if (thislist == "stan") {
                $('<div class="standard" style="text-align:left;border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;margin: 0px;padding-top: 0.5em;padding-left: 0.4em;padding-right: 0px;padding-bottom: 0.5em;font-size: 0.9em;line-height: 90%;"></div>').html('<a href="listingsMob.html?Standard=' + Standard2 + '" target="_top" style="text-decoration: none;padding-left: 10px;background-image: url(images/open_arrow.gif);background-position: bottom left;background-repeat: no-repeat;">' + Standard2 + '</a>').appendTo("#standards");
            } if (thislist == "cert") {
                $('<div class="certify" style="text-align:left;border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;margin: 0px;padding-top: 0.5em;padding-left: 0.4em;padding-right: 0px;padding-bottom: 0.5em;font-size: 0.9em;line-height: 90%;"></div>').html('<a href="listingsMob.html?Certified=' + Certify2 + '" target="_top" style="text-decoration: none;padding-left: 10px;background-image: url(images/open_arrow.gif);background-position: bottom left;background-repeat: no-repeat;">' + Certify2 + '</a>').appendTo("#certified");
            }
        });
        // because this is in a for each loop, it may list the returned variables multiple times so
        // remove duplicate returned variable appearances
        var mapAddedComany = {};
        //alert('comes here');
        $(".company").each(function () {
            var value = $(this).text();
            if (mapAddedComany[value] == null) {
                mapAddedComany[value] = true;
            } else {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
        var mapAddedProduct = {};
        $(".product").each(function () {
            var value = $(this).text();
            if (mapAddedProduct[value] == null) {
                mapAddedProduct[value] = true;
            } else {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
        var mapAddedStandard = {};
        $(".standard").each(function () {
            var value = $(this).text();
            if (mapAddedStandard[value] == null) {
                mapAddedStandard[value] = true;
            } else {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
        var mapAddedCertify = {};
        $(".certify").each(function () {
            var value = $(this).text();
            if (mapAddedCertify[value] == null) {
                mapAddedCertify[value] = true;
            } else {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
        return false;
    },
    $.ajax(Params);
}
```

I have been searching forums for two days and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove `var thislist;`, it is redundant.

Comment: chances are var thislist; clears your variable

Comment: I appreciate the help. I tried removing var thislist and it didn't change. The error alert still says 'undefined'.

Comment: You get `undefined`, because you have to use `alert(errorThrown);` (without `xhr.` before the variable). Then you get the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error".